# Prove by contradiction, that for every $x ∈ [ π /2, π ]$, $\sin x − \cos x \ge 1$

Tags: trigonometry, solution-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

I feel like I made some mistake along the way. Can somebody check, and explain if it's correct. The book provided different solution to this one.

For the sake of contradiction suppose that there exists $x\in[\frac{\pi}{2}, \pi]$, $\sin (x)-\cos(x)<1$. With algebraic and trig manipulations we get:
$$\sin(x)<1+\cos(x)$$
$$\sin^2(x)<1+2\cos(x)+\cos^2(x)$$
$$1-\cos^2(x)<1+2\cos(x)+\cos^2(x)$$
$$-2\cos^2(x)<2\cos(x)$$
$$-2\cos^2(x)-2\cos(x)<0$$
Dividing by $-2\cos(x)$ leads to:
$$\cos(x)+1<0$$

Since we know that $\cos(x)$ on the interval $[\frac{\pi}{2}, \pi]$ is between $0$ and $1$, $\cos(x)+1$ can't be lower than $0$. Thus contradiction.

Comment: Looks fine. It is better to mention that $\sin x$ and $-2\cos x$ are positive . (This has been used in the argument)

Comment: Note that $\cos x$ is not between $0$ and $1$ in $[-\pi/2, \pi]$, but it is between $-1$ and $0$. For this reason you were allowed to divide by $-2\cos x$ without changing the inequality. The conclusion still holds. Similarly you should have discussed that $\sin x>0$ when you took the squares (first step).

Comment: As hinted at in other comments, the final contradiction statement needs to be corrected, but the rest appears ok (with justifications).

Comment: @ECL meant $cosx$ between -1 and 0. Thanks. But only with your hint realized, that dividing by $-2cos(x)$ i should had changed inequality. You wrote, that I'm allowed to divide so without changing. But i can't warp head around why. Can you explain?
And why to discuss that $sinx>0$

Comment: When $x=\pi/2$, $-2\cos x =0$. Hence you cannot divide by it. Also, you can use \cos and \sin to produce $\cos$ and $\sin$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For the sake of contradiction suppose that there exists $x\in\left[\frac{\pi}{2}, \pi\right],\; \sin (x)-\cos(x)<1$.
>
> $$\sin(x)<1+\cos(x)$$ $$\sin^2(x)<1+2\cos(x)+\cos^2(x)$$

You should justify this step (squaring an inequality while preserving its direction) by pointing out that $x^2$ is increasing for nonnegative $x$ and $\sin(x)$ is nonnegative on $\left[\frac{\pi}{2}, \pi\right].$

> $$1-\cos^2(x)<1+2\cos(x)+\cos^2(x)$$ $$-2\cos^2(x)<2\cos(x)$$
> $$-2\cos^2(x)-2\cos(x)<0$$

So far so good.

> Dividing by $-2\cos(x)$ leads to:
> $$\cos(x)+1<0$$
> Since we know that $\cos(x)$ on the interval $\left[\frac{\pi}{2}, \pi\right]$ is
> between $0$ and $1$, $\cos(x)+1$ can't be lower than $0$. Thus
> contradiction.

Don't you mean that $\cos$ is between $-1$ and $0\,?$ And you neglected to point out that you are dividing by a positive number (because $-2\cos(x)\ge0$ and $x\ne\frac\pi2).$

Alternatively, here's a more straightforward continuation: $$(\cos x)(\cos x+1)>0\\
(\cos x)\;\&\;(\cos x+1)\;\text{are either both positive or both negative}\\
\cos x\notin[-1,0].$$

That is, $\cos x\notin[-1,0]$ for some $x\in\left[\frac{\pi}{2},\pi\right].$

Since, in fact, $\cos x\in[-1,0]$ for all $x\in\left[\frac{\pi}{2}, \pi\right],$ we have a contradiction.